# asp.net core routing parameter is always null

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an actionresult method, which accepts a string as parameter, but whenever I query that method with url, that parameter is always null.

`abc` is the value of id in routing.
but when I look at the stack trace I dont see method accepting any value.

```
http://localhost:47268/admin/AllQuarterEvent/abc
```

```
public IActionResult AllQuarterEventByMap(string map)
{
    return View(_staffMethods.GetQuarterEventsByMap(map));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this solution :

```
  [HttpGet("admin/AllQuarterEventByMap/{map}")]
  public IActionResult AllQuarterEventByMap([fromRoute] string map)
    {
        return View(_staffMethods.GetQuarterEventsByMap(map));
    }
```

Comment: How do u do this with a post though